# Replace and fill columns without warning

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I need to replace any Unnamed values in Type, and after that, I need to Fill in the data, but I have the warning I don't know how to solve this. Any suggestion?

```
    Date    Column1 Total     Type    N    P
2   04/2019       2   NaN       Type1  NaN  NaN
3   05/2019       2   NaN       Type1  NaN  NaN
4   06/2019       2     2       Type1   14  NaN
5   07/2019       4     4       Type1   16  NaN
8   04/2019       2   NaN  Unnamed: 4  NaN  NaN
9   05/2019       2   NaN  Unnamed: 4  NaN  NaN
10  06/2019       2     2  Unnamed: 4  NaN   10
11  07/2019       4     4  Unnamed: 4  NaN   15
14  04/2019       2   NaN       Type2  NaN  NaN
```

This is my code with warning:

```
table['Type'][table.Type.str.contains('Unnamed')] = np.NaN
```

the warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

And I need to fill

```
table['Type'] = table['Type'].ffill()
```

Output:

```
           Date Column1 Total    Type    N    P
    2   04/2019       2   NaN   Type1  NaN  NaN
    3   05/2019       2   NaN   Type1  NaN  NaN
    4   06/2019       2     2   Type1   14  NaN
    5   07/2019       4     4   Type1   16  NaN
    8   04/2019       2   NaN   Type1  NaN  NaN
    9   05/2019       2   NaN   Type1  NaN  NaN
    10  06/2019       2     2   Type1  NaN   10
    11  07/2019       4     4   Type1  NaN   15
    14  04/2019       2   NaN   Type2  NaN  NaN
```

And I have, one more time the same warning, for this code:

```
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

How can I solve this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `replace` function followed by a call to `ffill` as well:

```
df["Type"] = df["Type"].replace(regex="Unnamed", value=np.nan).ffill()

print(df)
       Date  Column1  Total   Type     N     P
2   04/2019        2    NaN  Type1   NaN   NaN
3   05/2019        2    NaN  Type1   NaN   NaN
4   06/2019        2    2.0  Type1  14.0   NaN
5   07/2019        4    4.0  Type1  16.0   NaN
8   04/2019        2    NaN  Type1   NaN   NaN
9   05/2019        2    NaN  Type1   NaN   NaN
10  06/2019        2    2.0  Type1   NaN  10.0
11  07/2019        4    4.0  Type1   NaN  15.0
14  04/2019        2    NaN  Type2   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Replace function followed by a call to fill works, but I continue with the warning message:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  table["Type"] = table["Type"].replace(regex="Unnamed", value=np.nan).ffill()

Comment: This means that your `table` variable is a subset from a larger dataframe. Did you define your table as `table = some_df.loc[...]`? You can always try `table = table.copy()` which should stop you from seeing that warning.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error says, use `.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer]`. In this case, `table.Type.str.contains('Unnamed')` is `row_indexer` and `Type` is `col_indexer`. So:

```
table.loc[table.Type.str.contains('Unnamed'), 'Type'] = np.NaN
```

Comment: I receive the same message error:
C:\Users\User01\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:670: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas....
C:\Users\User01\Desktop\File.py:67: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html
  table.loc[table.Type.str.contains('Unnamed'), 'Type'] = np.NaN

Comment: Your `table` is a slice of some other dataframe. Try `table=table.copy()` before modifying it.